When using Mapster a new object is created on destination instead of null when using Adapt<>
I have the following classes:
ScheduleWrapper
 public Guid ID { get; set; }  
 public Guid? CompanyID { get; set; }  
 public CItyWrapper City {get;set;}  
 public CItyWrapper City1 {get;set;}  

Schedule
 public Guid ID { get; set; }
 public Guid? CompanyID { get; set; }
 public Company Company { get; set; }
 public CIty Start{get;set;}
 public CIty End {get;set;}

When I try to adapt ScheduleWrapper to Schedule, on Schedule an empty Company object will be created instead of null.
Other configurations are:
config.Default.PreserveReference(true);
config.Default.IgnoreNullValues(true);
config.NewConfig<Schedule, ScheduleWrapper>().TwoWays()
                .Map(dest => dest.City, src => src.Start)
                .Map(dest => dest.City1, src => src.End);

I noticed this behavior also in other places where the explicit mapping is not defined.
Is there a setting to not create empty objects on destination when the property does not exist on source?
I tried also creating a custom DestinationTransform, but without success (I am not sure it is working as expected, as I adapted mine using the existing "DestinationTransform.CreateNewIfNull")
        public static readonly DestinationTransform KeepNull = new DestinationTransform()
        {
            Condition = (type => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null && !type.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface && !type.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract && type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SingleOrDefault(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 0) != null),
            TransformFunc = (type =>
            {
                ParameterExpression left = Expression.Parameter(type);
                return Expression.Lambda(left);
            })
        };


Can you please provide a [mre] which can be easily run?
